# My pygame code won't accept input

Tags: python, pygame

this code wont accept input and i have no idea why its been stressing me out for days please help me if you can

```
while True:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   sys.exit()
   break
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
   for x in range (0, 29):
    if event.key == keys[b]:
     if keys[b] == pygame.K_TAB:
      now = not now
      break
      break
     if keys[b] == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
      user = lett[b]
      break
      break
     else:
      user += lett[b]
      break
      break
  else:
   b += 1
```

Comment: What pax said, it's an indentation issue mostly. However there's strange code. I don't understand what the `x` and `lett` code is supposed to do. And two breaks in a row do nothing more than one.

Answer (score 1):

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
  sys.exit()
  break
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

It looks like your `for` and second `if` are at the same indent level.

That means you're likely to read all events in the `for` loop and basically throw away the ones that aren't `QUIT`.

This may have been a lot clearer had you stuck to the guidelines of a four-space indent - I suspect what you need to do is to indent the second `if` so that it's at the same indent level as the first.